# How to select first element in each group using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given the following HTML input:

```
<p>A</p>
<p>B</p>
<p>C</p>
<div>D</div>
<p>E</p>
<p>F</p>
<p>G</p>
```

I can use the following to select *B*, *C*, *F* and *G*:

```
$('p + p')
```

How can I select *A* and *E*?

```
$('???').each(function() {
    var restOfGroup = $(this).next('p');
});
```

Comment: `$('p:not(p+p)')`

Comment: jQuery's [`nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/) might be useful for selecting `restOfGroup` : `var restOfGroup = $(this).nextUntil(':not(p)');`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the inverse:

```
$('p:not(p+p)')
```

- [Demo](http://jsbin.com/citaji/1/edit)
- [`:not` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)
- `+` [Next adjacent selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/)

Comment: what is meant by p +p ??

Comment: @EhsanSajjad `+ == next sibling`, so it mean a `p` that follow a `p`.